# Does Xuggler generate RTSP stream

Tags: java, rtsp, xuggler

Is it possible to generate RTSP video stream with Xuggler? If so can you give an outline of the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the same thing and even if I didn't manage to make it work, I can start to point you in the right direction:

First, RTSP is only the control channel. It is like HTTP and it is used to send commands like `PLAY`, `PAUSE`, and to setup the streaming. The real streaming can be realized in a lot of ways, the most common maybe is RTP-RTCP over UDP.
For the RTSP part the only way to understand and correctly implement it is going throug the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326). You have to implement at least the OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, PLAY, PAUSE, SETUP and TEARDOWN methods.

Once you have a server that speaks RTSP and agrees with the client on a pair of ports for RTP and RTCP, you have to open the media file you want to stream in a `IContainer` (direction IN), get one stream (every stream must setup his RTP-RTCP port pair so one for audio, one for video, etc.), start reading the packets with `ReadNextPacket(IPacket)` and use the `getData(IBuffer)` method to fill a RTP packet and send it to the client.
To control the RTP flow (like send rate, jitter, loss rate, etc.) you can also use the RTCP socket to send/receive reports.
Again, the starting point for those protocols are the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550).